# ¿Son redundantes las acepciones del verbo "callar"?

Tags: verbos, significado, acepciones

Echemos un vistazo a las acepciones del verbo *callar*:

> **[callar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6pebbaT)**
>
> Del lat. vulg. **callāre* 'callar', 'bajar', y este del gr. *χαλᾶν chalân* 'hacer bajar'.
>
> 1. tr. Omitir o no decir algo. U. t. c. prnl.
> 2. intr. Dicho de una persona: No hablar, guardar silencio. *Calla como un muerto.* U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. intr. Cesar de hablar. *Cuando esto hubo dicho, calló.* U. t. c. prnl.
> 4. intr. Cesar de llorar, de gritar, de cantar, de tocar un instrumento musical, de meter bulla o ruido. U. t. c. prnl.
> 5. intr. Abstenerse de manifestar lo que se siente o se sabe. U. t. c. prnl.
> 6. intr. Dicho de ciertos animales: Cesar en sus voces; p. ej., dejar de cantar un pájaro, de ladrar un perro, de croar una rana, etc. U. t.
>      c. prnl.
> 7. intr. Dicho del mar, del viento, de un volcán, etc.: Dejar de hacer ruido. U. t. c. prnl. U. m. en leng. poét.
> 8. intr. Dicho de un instrumento musical: Cesar de sonar. U. t. c. prnl.

No sé a vosotros, pero a mí me da la sensación de que las acepciones 5 a 8 son redundantes:

- La acepción 5 se puede incluir en la 1. Es cierto que la primera se refiere al verbo como transitivo, y la quinta como intransitivo. Pero debemos tener en cuenta que un verbo transitivo no necesita un complemento directo (CD) sino que lo admite, pero puede ir omitido: *Juan leyó y leyó hasta que se le cerraron los ojos de sueño.* El verbo *leer* es transitivo en todas sus acepciones, pero aquí se omite el CD. De forma similar, la acepción 5 puede ser igual que la 1 cuando el CD se omite.
- La acepción 4 ya da la idea de *callar(se)* como "cesar de emitir(se) un sonido". Luego la acepción 6 ("cesar de cantar un pájaro", "dejar de ladrar un perro") se incluye en esta (de hecho se podría considerar también incluida en la acepción 3 si se consideran los sonidos animales como sus formas de hablar). Y lo mismo con la acepción 7 ("dejar de emitir sonido un evento atmosférico") y la 8 ("dejar de sonar un instrumento"), que directamente están incluidas en la 4.

Me gustaría centrarme en todo caso en este segundo punto. ¿Son las acepciones 6, 7 y 8 redundantes existiendo ya la 4? ¿O existe alguna diferencia entre ambas? ¿Existe algún motivo por el que existan las acepciones 6 a 8 de forma separada?

Comment: Para mi la 4 resume todo y sería aun más simple si solo dijera "cesar o abstenerse de emitir sonido" :-) al estilo translation golf.

Comment: @DGaleano y Charlie - Es cierto, y supongo que así lo haría otro tipo de diccionario.  Pero el DRAE no es un diccionario que sintetice definiciones, es un diccionario que separa cada pelito con ligeros matices diferentes.

Comment: @walen - ¿Por qué no haces una respuesta de tu primer comentario?  Yo daría mi voto. // ¿Qué es CD?

Comment: @aparente001 "Complemento directo", está explicado en la pregunta.

Comment: @Charlie - Ah sí, perdón, gracias.

Comment: @walen - Me gusta tu explicación en tu segundo comentario también.

Comment: @walen - Sí, en general es mejor tener documentación.  Pero temo que la pregunta se borre automáticamente si no recibe respuestas.  Espero que plasmes tus ideas en la forma de Respuesta si dentro de un par de días no se ha aportado nada todavía.

Comment: @aparente001 las preguntas sin respuesta no se borran, [se quedan ahí esperando indefinidamente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) a que algún caballero andante las rescate.

Comment: @Charlie - En ELU aprendí que depende de los votos.  Las preguntas con voto <= 0 se borran.  Bueno, estrictamente, esta pregunta no pertenece a esa clase.  Pero yo pienso que hay que ser un poco elástico con las normas en caso de una pregunta difícil como esta. // Por cierto, a tí te gusta entablar diálogo con la RAE, ¿le has dirigido esta pregunta?

Comment: @aparente001 lo haré si tras unos días nadie se anima a responder. :-)

Comment: @Charlie - Maybe you can post a link to this question and finally get them to take the bait to come *here* to answer.

Comment: @aparente001 [Won't fall that fig](http://dle.rae.es/?id=65O598P#8q8hlO4).

Comment: @Charlie - I guess you mean *that fig won't fall* [That'll be the day]?  Sadly, it doesn't work in English. // So, you think it's hopeless?  The RAE is a hamster that can't be coaxed out of its igloo, no matter how attractive the chewing stick you jiggle in the doorway?  (I recently adopted a hamster.)

Comment: @aparente001 no pretendía que funcionara en inglés, era una traducción literal (y jocosa) que ahora están tan de moda por aquí (como decir "from lost to the river" para la expresión española "de perdidos al río"). La RAE siempre responde usando el mismo medio: si publicas el link en Twitter responderá por Twitter. Si le escribes un correo responderá por correo.

Comment: @Charlie - Ah, gracias por explicar el juego. ¿No se tiene que respetar la sintaxis? ¿O se considera más divertido hacer una traducción un tanto *butchered*? Si se debe hacer una buena traducción, propongo *All is lost.  To the river!* Pero ¿quizás se trata precisamente de hacer una traducción súper literal y horrible? // La RAE: si nomás se le da el enlace, sin copiar el contenido de la pregunta, ¿contestarán?

Answer (score 1):

Estoy de acuerdo en que la manera en la que se desglosan las aplicaciones del verbo parecen excesivas y podrían condensarse en una enunciación más genérica. Las definiciones del 6 al 8 resultan redundantes con las de punto 4, que en realidad aluden a:

> **Hacer silencio alguien o algo con posibilidad de romperlo.**

En definitiva todas expresan:

> **Abstenerse o cesar de emitir voces, exclamaciones y sonido alguno por parte de una persona, animal u objeto**
>
> - "*La testigo no declaró una palabra, calló todo el tiempo su versión con el rostro mudo en una mirada contenida y sufriente*"
> - "*Cuando irrumpió, deslumbrante, en la fiesta, hasta la orquesta calló*"
> - "*Cesó la lluvia y calló el viento, todo volvió a la calma *"

Answer (score -2):

No Lo creo :

> 1.tr. Omitir o no decir algo. U. t. c. prnl. -- ej. **Callé lo inecesario** (obviar)
>   2.intr. Dicho de una persona: No hablar, guardar silencio. *Calla como un muerto.* U. t. c. prnl. -- ej. **Callé toda la noche** (no hablé)
>   3.intr. Cesar de hablar. *Cuando esto hubo dicho, calló.* U. t. c. prnl. -- ej. **callé** (terminé)
>   4.intr. Cesar de llorar, de gritar, de cantar, de tocar un instrumento musical, de meter bulla o ruido. U. t. c. prnl. -- ej. **¡Callense!** (guarden silencio)
>   5.intr. Abstenerse de manifestar lo que se siente o se sabe. U. t. c. prnl. -- ej. **Callé mi secreto** (me guardé mi secreto)
>   6.intr. Dicho de ciertos animales: Cesar en sus voces; p. ej., dejar de cantar un pájaro, de ladrar un perro, de croar una rana, etc. U. t.c. prnl. **(auto explicatorio)**
>   7.intr. Dicho del mar, del viento, de un volcán, etc.: Dejar de hacer ruido. U. t. c. prnl. U. m. en leng. poét. -- ej. **el volcan calló** (la erupción terminó)
>   8.intr. Dicho de un instrumento musical: Cesar de sonar. U. t. c. prnl. -- ej. **calla tu violin** (deja de tocar tu violin)

Creo que se siente la redundancia porque todas estan relacionadas al sonido, sin embargo, cada uso tiene un significado diferente.

Hay que indicar que viene etimológicamente del latin **callāre* que significa "bajar la voz" o "guardar silencio". Sin embargo su uso es para representar las distintas formas en las que se guarda silencio.

Por ejemplo, en el primer caso tenemos que obviar y callar son sinónimos.

Comment: Lo corrijo mas tarde, nuevamente estoy en una pc que me autocorrige al ingles

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! No me cuadra el ejemplo que pones para la acepción 8, que se refiere a un uso intransitivo, dado que "tu violín" sería el complemento directo y por tanto el uso del verbo sería transitivo. Lo mismo pasa con el ejemplo de la acepción 5.

Comment: @Mike - Si te faltan los acentos en una computadora ajena, o si tienes alguna falta de ortografía sin tu spell checker, entiendo, pero mira que se puede formatear el texto en cualquier lado con asteriscos.  Por otro lado, proofreading se puede hacer dondequiera.  Mira por ejemplo *Hay que indicar viene*.  Chequea también dónde hace falta una letra mayúscula.  Gracias.  Yo pienso que haces buenas aportaciones al sitio; me gustaría ver que pusieras ahora más cuidado a tus posts, de manera más consistente.