# ¿Hay alguna diferencia sustancial entre las dos primeras acepciones de "barrer"?

Tags: verbos, acepciones

El otro día se preguntaba [¿Son redundantes las acepciones del verbo “callar”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23400/son-redundantes-las-acepciones-del-verbo-callar) y yo tenía la sensación de que en el diccionario de la RAE muchas palabras tienen acepciones demasiado similares y otras veces faltan acepciones bastante obvias que sí incluyen otros diccionarios pero esto último sería otro debate.

Quizá en algunas de estas acepciones haya pequeños matices que se me escapan pero he visto una palabra con dos acepciones que yo diría que son exactamente iguales, solo cambia el orden de un par de palabras, aquí está:

> **[barrer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=57tYdu7)**
>   **1.** tr. Limpiar un lugar arrastrando la suciedad con algo como una escoba.
>   **2.** tr. Limpiar la suciedad de un lugar arrastrándola con algo como una escoba.

¿Tiene algún sentido mantener estas dos acepciones prácticamente idénticas? Incluso aunque hubiera una ligera diferencia ¿es suficiente para justificar una acepción más?

Comment: Como dice Mauricio, el objeto de la acción es diferente (el lugar vs. la sustancia).  Interesante la pregunta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pues sí veo una diferencia, aunque es sutil, como dices.

La primera acepción se enfoca en el lugar que se está limpiando. En este caso el lugar es quien recibe la acción. Ejemplo: Barrer el piso.
La segunda acepción, siguiendo con el ejemplo del piso, se concentra en lo que se quiere quitar de él, como podría ser basura u otra cosa que se quiera remover. Por ejemplo: ¡Barre esos trozos de vidrio roto que alguien se puede lastimar!

Con los dos ejemplos de arriba en mente, se podría decir también que al "barrer el piso" significa barrer todo el piso, como una actividad de aseo rutinaria. Pero barrer "algo" del piso (por ejemplo los trozos de vidrio) puede significar barrer solamente donde ese "algo" está.

Comment: Cierto, ahora que lo dices con ejemplos sí hay una diferencia que no había visto.

Comment: Esta una de las respuestas ganadoras a nuestro [concurso de las mejores preguntas de 2017](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2787/5481). Enhorabuena. Gracias por tus fabulosas contribuciones!

Comment: ¡Genial! Muchas gracias :)